# How to calculate the average of even and odd numbers in an array?

Tags: java

As a class exercise I have to code using methods a program that:

1) Calculates the average of even and odd numbers in an array.

I expect on using one method to find the average of even and odd numbers. However, I'm having trouble on returning the right average. For example, if I enter only odd numbers I get an error, and vice versa.

This error:
"java.lang.ArithmeticException: / zero"

Also, if it were possible I would like to get some help on coding the rest of the exercise which asks for:

2) Print the highest and lowest number in the array
3) Allow the user to modify any of the numbers of the array

So far I have this code:

```
public static void main (String args[]){

    int x[] = new int[4];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length ; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        x[i] = input.nextInt();
    }


    System.out.println("Average of even numbers: " + getAverage(x));
    System.out.println("Average of odd numbers: " + getAverage(x));

 }

public static int getAverage(int a[]){
    int add_even = 0;
    int counter_even = 0;
    int average_even = 0;

    int add_odd = 0;
    int counter_odd = 0;
    int average_odd = 0;


    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if(a[i] % 2 == 0){
            add_even += a[i];
            counter_even++;
        }
        else if(a[i] % 2 == 1) {
            add_odd += a[i];
            counter_odd++;
        }

    }

    if (add_even % 2 == 1 && add_odd % 2 == 1){
    average_even = 0;
    average_odd = add_odd / counter_odd;

    return average_even;
   }
   else if (add_even % 2 == 0 && add_odd % 2 == 0){
    average_even = add_even / counter_even;
    average_odd = 0;

    return average_even;
    }
   else{

    average_even = 0;
    average_odd = add_odd / counter_odd;

    return average_odd;

    }


}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Explain what result you're getting from this, and ask a clearer question based on what's actually causing you a problem. This is too close to asking people to do your homework for you.

Comment: Let's say I enter 4 times the number 3 (an odd number). I get a message that says "java.lang.ArithmeticException: / zero"

Comment: average = sum/number of elements. when you only enter even or odd, then the number of elements of the other is zero, hence you end up dividing by zero.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that might be the reason, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, however I have a guess - are you dividing by zero?

Comment: Put there some kind of check: `if(there is no zero) {divide} else {do something else}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your get average looks more complicated then it needs to be.

First off the `getAverage(x)`:

```
System.out.println("Average of even numbers: " + getAverage(x));
    System.out.println("Average of odd numbers: " + getAverage(x));
```

will return the same value, so if you wanted to get the average for odds or evens the method should require a boolean arg to represent odd or even.

In your method you should loop through all the numbers and check if it is even.  If it is even and you are averaging evens add it to a "total" and add one to a counter.  At the end divide "total" by the counter and return the value.  The average will most likely include a decimal value, so you should return a double or a float.

Example:

```
public static double getAverage(int a[], boolean even){
  double total = 0;//These are doubles so dividing later does not require casting to retain a decimal (this can be an int if you only want to return integers)
    double counter = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
    if(a[i] % 2 == 0 && even){//even
      counter++;
      total += a[i];
    }else{//odd
      counter++;
      total += a[i];
    }
  }
  if(total == 0){//Avoid dividing by 0.
    return 0; //You can also throw an exception instead of returning 0.
  }
  return total / counter; //Returns the average for even or odd numbers.
}
```

For the second part of your question you need to loop through the numbers and find the highest and lowest while looping.

Example:

```
int highest = 0;
int lowest = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
  if(x[i] > highest){
    highest = x[i];
  }
  if(x[i] < lowest){
    lowest = x[i];
  }
  if(i == 0){
    highest = x[i];
    lowest = x[i];  
  }
}
```

Comment: When printing using this statement: 

System.out.println("Average of even numbers: " + getAverage(x));

I get the message that it requires an "int" + a boolean. 

I write then

System.out.println("Average of even numbers: " + getAverage(x,even));

 but it says that it cannot fin the symbol "even"

Comment: @PBRD That is because it is requiring a `boolean` which is true or false.  So just put in `true` for finding the even average or false` for finding the odd average.

Comment: It works that way, but it gives me the same value for both even and odd averages.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. I had to create a second method for checking average of odd numbers and then I removed the "else" from both methods, since counter and total were adding numbers either way... and the "if" down below made the validation not to divide by 0.

Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You have a divide by zero error cropping up here.

```
else if (add_even % 2 == 0 && add_odd % 2 == 0){
    average_even = add_even / counter_even;
    average_odd = 0;
    return average_even;
}
```

`0 % 2 == 0` so even if add_even is 0 (and as a result, so is counter_even) you're attempting to use it to divide. You'll need to account for that in your code by checking if counter_even is 0.

```
else if (counter_even != 0 && add_even % 2 == 0 && add_odd % 2 == 0){
```

Comment: mmm...by doing this validation I was trying to make a difference between even and odd numbers. So if the addition of the numbers inside the array were even I wanted the code to return only the average of even numbers.

Comment: This can still work, you can just add a condition here that counter_even isn't 0. I'll add that to my answer to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

1)Using one method to get the average of the even and odd numbers isn't proper because you only `return` one `int`. It would be simpler to use two methods but if you're insistent on using one method you could add a `boolean` as a parameter like this to decide which to do. To handle the `ArithmeticException` just `return` `0` if there are no values.

```
public static int average(int[] n, boolean even) {
     int total = 0;
     int count = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
          if (even == (n % 2 == 0)) {
               total += n;
               count ++;
          }
     }
     if (count == 0)
          return 0;
     return total / count;
```

2)To check find the max and min value simply loop through the array like this

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     if (x[i] < min)
          min = x[i];
     if (x[i] > max)
          max = x[i];
}
```

3)To allow the user to modify the array, you could print the values and prompt them as to which value they would like to change like this.

```
System.out.print("Array: ");
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     System.out.print(i + ",");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Which value would you like to change?");
int index = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("What do you want the new value to be?");
int value = input.nextInt();
```

You can then run a method that changes the value of the array

```
edit(x, index, value);

public static int edit(int[] n, int index, int value) {
     n[index] = value;
     return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used **JS** for this task, you can just rewrite my code to **Java** language.

> A number is divisible by 2 if the result of its division by 2 has no
>   remainder or fractional component - in other terms if the result is an
>   integer. Zero is an even number because when 0 is divided by
>   2, the resulting quotient turns out to also be 0 - an integer (as a
>   whole number that can be written without a remainder, 0 classifies as
>   an integer).

```js
function compareEvenOddAverage(arr) {
let even = 0,
    odd = 0,
    evenCounter = 0,
    oddCounter = 0,
    str = '';

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
        even += arr[i];
        evenCounter++;
    } else {
        odd += arr[i];
        oddCounter++;
    }
}

if (even / evenCounter > odd / oddCounter) {
    str += 'Average value of even numbers is greater';
} else if (even / evenCounter < odd / oddCounter) {
    str += 'Average value of odd numbers is greater';
} else {
    str += 'Average values are equal';
}

return str;
}

console.log(compareEvenOddAverage([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```